# TeamCity conditional/dynamic dependencies

Tags: dependencies, teamcity

I'm not sure how to accomplish what we need, if it is even possible, or even a good idea. We have a build configuration that creates an iso for release and for testing. Typically we rigger a build off a specific set of branch names. Some of these branch names are controlled by the build system, some can be created by the user for creating a test build of experimental code. We'd like to setup project dependencies to trigger tests and include the final step in the build chain, still use the same configuration for making a test build

So ultimately under some conditions we want a project dependencies, under other conditions we do not.

we are currently on 2017.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a planned feature in version 2018.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-19132

As workaround they suggest to download artefacts in custom build step

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep my eye out for that